# Saving an asp.net chart to file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bar chart containing information on various machines relating to company.

Basically i want to output this chart to png file but i cant seem to get it output properly.

Ive been searching Google for hours trying to find a good tutorial but most of them use weird third party components to download the image and i really dont wanna do that.

this is my code at the moment:

```
string tmpChartName = "/MachinesByCompanyChart.png";

  protected void GenerateBarChartBut_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chart1.Visible = false;
            Chart2.Visible = true;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            dal.getTotalAssetsByCompany("table", TAB1CompanyDDL.SelectedItem.Text);

            table = dal.Results.Tables["table"];

            DataView dv = table.DefaultView;

            Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(dv, "AssetType", dv, "Total");

            Chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;

            Chart2.PaletteCustomColors = myGreenColorPalette;


            string imgPath2 = Server.MapPath(tmpChartName);
            Chart2.SaveImage(imgPath2, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        }

        protected void ExportAssetsByCompanyBut_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = Chart1.ImageType.ToString();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + tmpChartName);
            StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            string headerTable = @"";
            Response.Write(headerTable);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End(); 
        }
```

Am i passing the saved image to the writer method properly?

Comment: can you provide your chart code (aspx.page side)?

Comment: i have provide you code also. you can try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

set this two properties of your chart in aspx.page

```
EnableViewState="true"
ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
```

write your code on aspx.cs page

```
System.IO.MemoryStream imagestream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
Chart1.SaveImage(imagestream, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
byte[] imageByte = imagestream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you manish, this approach works but i needed to edit your code to get it to do what i wanted. I will edit your answer with the full solution

Comment: @Kendo do you still have the changes that you needed to make?